# Do you lose in 8 ball pool if the 8 ball hits another ball

Tags: rules, pool

Regular 8 call pocket pool you are on the 8 ball for the win. You call your pocket. You shoot and hit the 8 ball. It's going for the pocket you called, but hits another ball on the way and still goes in the pocket that was called. Do you lose the game